# Replacing Line Breaks with <br> returns null | PHP

Tags: php, html

Replacing line breaks with `<br>` in php is always returning null.

My Code:

```
echo 'message: '.$message.', ';
$message =  nl2br($message);
echo 'message: '.$message;
```

```
echo 'message: '.$message.', ';
$message = preg_replace('/\v+|\\\r\\\n/Ui','<br/>',$message);
echo 'message: '.$message;
```

Return always looks like:
"message: 'proper string', message: null"

Theory: Something's up with my server settings.

I can't find anything about this online.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, what does `$message` contain?

Comment: 'test'. I figured it out. Some weird issue about assigning the $message variable to the function return. This works: ```  $message2 =  nl2br($message);
  $message = $message2;``` It would be cool to know why that fixes it.

Comment: There's no way that can make a difference.

Comment: The code as it is right now should also work, totally fine.

Comment: Also, echoing `null` echoes an empty string, not the word `null`.

Comment: I know, I put null just to make it obvious. The actual return I was getting was 'message: test, message:' It's weird, and seems as though it's an issue isolated to my server considering you cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Are there any special characters in `$message` other than newline? It could be an encoding issue.

Comment: I'm pulling the string from a textarea input and passing it thought a XHR request as ```formData.append('message', $holder.find('.post-text-area textarea').val())```. I've tested with and without a new line and issue applies to both versions.

Comment: What server are you using then?

Comment: I've tested 'test' and 'test\nnow' newline generated through pressing enter on a keyboard.

Comment: `'test\nnow'` in single quotes doesn't produce a newline, `"test\nnow"` using double quotes does

Comment: Whatever hostgator gave me lol

Comment: and I didn't actually include quotes. I let jquery handle the string. and I didn't write out a new line. I pressed enter on my keyboard.

Comment: Appreciate you looking into it for me. I'm glad my fix works for now. It's just weird.

Comment: When you're debugging, use `var_dump()` rather than `echo`.

Comment: Turn up your `error_reporting` level, `nl2br()` is probably generating a warning that tells you why it's returning null.